# TIC TCP Conn Failed 1:54 Err(54)

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, app-transport-security

I am attempting to make POST requests to a secure server in my app, without a certificate.  When I make a request I'm getting these errors in the console:

`2018-04-24 16:14:22.942030-0400 TIC TCP Conn Failed [8:0x60000017c440]: 1:54 Err(54)
2018-04-24 16:14:22.942779-0400 Task <1E09E1AE-CE51-48C4-9A56-F3738B8FD68F>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [1:54])
2018-04-24 16:14:22.943219-0400 [93037:8075678] Task <1E09E1AE-CE51-48C4-9A56-F3738B8FD68F>.<1> finished with error - code: -1005`

In `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge` I'm not validating the certificate; I'm simply calling `continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge`.

I have my domain set as an exception for ATS in Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I can't find any documentation on what `Err(54)` and `error code: -1005` mean, so I'm running into a roadblock while troubleshooting.  It may also be worth mentioning that I have to connect my Mac to my VPN to ping this server, and that I'm running this in my simulator.

I'm hoping to hear some suggestions for what might be going wrong and how to fix.

Comment: What is the URL of the server you are connecting to?  HTTP / HTTPS?  The error you are seeing is not ATS related - it is just that the device / simulator cannot connect to the URL you are attempting to connect to.  To verify, go to Safari on the simulator and try hitting the same URL.

Comment: It is HTTPS.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I used a curl request to find that I could indeed make the request from command line, but I found that the issue was how I was handling (or not handling) the completion for `didReceiveChallenge`.  I'm going to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was with how I was handling `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge`.  I was only calling `continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge`.  What I did to get it to work was to call the `completionHandler` with a credential:

`SecTrustRef serverTrust = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
ASSERT(nil != serverTrust);
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust];
completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);`

Comment: Glad you tracked down the problem.  It didn't seem like an ATS error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what your ATS settings are allowing your app to do.

`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` being set to true allows you connect to any server over HTTP. So feel free to attempt to load data from any URL with the `http` scheme.

Your exception domain setting  (assuming that your "mydomain.net" is a placeholder for the actual value) will allow you to connect to any subdomain (because `NSIncludesSubdomains` is true) of "mydomain.net" using:

1. HTTP (because you have `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` set to true)

   - or -
2. An HTTPS connection that supports all the requirements of ATS except forward secrecy (because you have only set `NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` to true)

First, verify you can connect to the URL you are attempting to connect to from Safari on the device in question (in this case, the simulator).  Safari does not enforce ATS requirements, so you can see if it is ATS related.  If you cannot access the URL, it is related to the connection.  This could be server being unreachable, or it could be a problem with the certificate for a secure connection.  If this is the problem, you can probably get rid of any ATS exceptions you added trying to resolve the issue.

If you can connect to the resource, try to verify what ATS requirements are not being met so you can add the appropriate exceptions.  In the Terminal on your Mac, run the following to get a report on the server's compliance with ATS rules:

```
nscurl --ats-diagnostics <url>
```

This will tell you if the server doesn't support forward secrecy, or if the TLS version is too low.  Then you can add the specific ATS exceptions for that domain.

I still believe that there is another problem, as ATS errors in the log are usually very clear.  Your error seems like a general connectivity problem. You mention having your Mac connected to a VPN.  Does your VPN require you to use an HTTP/HTTPS proxy?  If so, I have had problems with the simulator trying to use the mac's proxy when the proxy requires certain types of authentication.  If your http proxy requires authentication, you might try standing up something like Charles Proxy as an intermediary.  i.e. setup Charles Proxy to authenticate to your company's proxy, then point the Mac / simulator to use the local Charles proxy which should be configured to not need authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the information. I removed the ATS exceptions for my domain.  It was in fact a certificate issue, and I was able to bypass the certificate validation as explained in my answer.  This is temporary as I'm working on a proof of concept, and when finalized and in production, I will have a proper certificate in the app so this will be unnecessary.