# Http calls not working ionic-webview (1.2.1) on iOS only on Cellular data

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, wkwebview, ionic-native

My Http calls to my backend service work fine on Android always and on WiFi on iOS, but as soon as I jump to cellular data I get the following errors `TIC TCP Conn Failed : Err(54)` and `HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [1:54])` which are the same error messages that are described here [TIC TCP Conn Failed 1:54 Err(54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010670/tic-tcp-conn-failed-154-err54) by the original question.

I have checked my ssl cert using `nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://api.mydomain.com` and everything passes other than TLSv1.3

I have also got the message `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error` from the HttpErrorResponse, which appears to relate to CORS, but it works under all scenarios other than cellular data on iOS, which suggests to me that it is not a CORS issue.

I have tried both Angular's HttpClient and cordova-plugin-advanced-http with no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My temporary fix for this has been to change my AWS Load Balancers to IPV4 instead of dual stack. I am still unsure about the root cause of this, but it is working for the time being. But this will need to be dual stack since Apple will complain next time I go to submit the app through them.